# How to define a composite solid with multiple arguments, including `Nothing`?

Tags: dagster

I have a solid that needs to run after 2 solids. One will return a value, another doesn't return anything but has dependency solids and will take time to run.

I execute the pipeline **in `multiprocessing` mode**, where solids run at the same time if they don't have dependencies defined.

Below is the sample situation I am looking for. Say I have below solids.

```py
@solid(input_defs=[InputDefinition("start", Nothing)])
def solid_a(context):
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    context.log.info('yey')

@solid
def solid_b(context):
    return 1

@composite_solid
def my_composite_solid(wait_solid_a: Nothing, solid_b_output: int):
    some_other_solid(solid_b_output)
```

And when executed, these solids will be running in the below timeline.

| Time Passed | solid |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | pipeline starts... |
| 1 sec | `solid_b` started |
| 3 sec | `solid_a` dependency solids are running. `solid_a` did not started yet. |
| 5 sec | `solid_b` finished |
| 10 sec | `solid_a` started now |
| 15 sec | `solid_a` finished |
| 20 sec | `my_composite_solid` **should start now**. |

So, according to this timeline, in order for `my_composite_solid` to start, I need both `solid_a` and `solid_b` to finish executing. However, when I make this, dagster throws an error saying:

```
dagster.core.errors.DagsterInvalidDefinitionError: @composite_solid 'my_composite_solid' has unmapped input 'wait_solid_a'. Remove it or pass it to the appropriate solid invocation.
```

If I don't put the `solid_a` output as a dependency to `my_composite_solid`, it will start immediately after the result of `solid_b`. What should I do?